# Embedded Linux for Mobile Development and Set top Box Application

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux

I am exploring on Embedded Linux for Mobile Development and Set top Box Application.
I need to do some R/D on Embedded Linux.

I found **BusyBox** is good for Set Top Box and **Maemo** for Mobile Development.

I wanted to know is there any Embedded Linux Distribution (open Source/free)   which can be used for both Mobile Development and Set top Box Application.

I also wanted to know  Other

1. Exclusively and widely used Embedded Linux For Mobile Development.
2. Exclusively and widely used Embedded Linux For Set Top Box.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand the words you wrote. Set top box is a type of hardware, there are many of those being manufactured, each needs its own stack of software (at least the hardware porting layer, the drivers and the bootstrap). On top of the hardware-dependent stack you can put the BusyBox utilities or Maemo, or whatever else. An example of such hardware is [Neuros OSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuros), with fully Open-Source software stack.

There's no one Linux distribution for embedded devices, as there's for PC's. Each device manufacturer tailors its own set of tools and drivers into the distribution they put on their devices. Most common examples are Android, BusyBox, etc., but it's not really a distribution in the sense you're used to in the PC world, because the actual kernel and drivers are hardware dependent and tailored.

Comment: Thnaks littleadv for your Reply.Since I am new, so might be my question is wrong.Sorry for that.Iwant to develop c++ application on any embedded Linux so that I acquire idea about the environment .Tell Me how should I proceed??

Comment: If it's just for learning - look at Neuros OSD - link in the answer.